# NoClassDefFoundError for org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.SubjectPublicKeyInfo when using Apache CXF

Tags: java, cxf, bouncycastle

I am getting a NoClassDefFoundError when trying to transmit a soap request with my app.

I've read that NoClassDefFoundError can often be caused by an exception initializing the class in question, but I've looked through the logs and this is the only error reported by the app.

I've been able to log the class name:

```
val classPath = SubjectPublicKeyInfo::class.java.getResource(SubjectPublicKeyInfo::class.java.simpleName + ".class").toString()
log.info("Class: $classPath")
```

And verified that the version of bouncy castle is the one expected by my version of Apache CXF:

```
implementation("org.apache.cxf:apache-cxf:3.3.5")
implementation("org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.54")
```

Could it be a problem with a different class loader? Or Tomcat doing ... something strange? Tomcat version is `7.0.76` and Java is java 8.

Exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/asn1/x509/SubjectPublicKeyInfo
org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.util.BaseKeyFactorySpi.engineGeneratePublic(Unknown Source)
org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.KeyFactorySpi.engineGeneratePublic(Unknown Source)
java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(KeyFactory.java:334)
sun.security.x509.X509Key.buildX509Key(X509Key.java:223)
sun.security.x509.X509Key.parse(X509Key.java:170)
sun.security.x509.CertificateX509Key.<init>(CertificateX509Key.java:75)
sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.parse(X509CertInfo.java:667)
sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.<init>(X509CertInfo.java:167)
sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.parse(X509CertImpl.java:1804)
sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.<init>(X509CertImpl.java:195)
sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate(X509Factory.java:102)
java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(CertificateFactory.java:339)
sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:716)
sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:224)
sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
org.apache.wss4j.common.crypto.Merlin.load(Merlin.java:370)
org.apache.wss4j.common.crypto.Merlin.loadProperties(Merlin.java:228)
org.apache.wss4j.common.crypto.Merlin.<init>(Merlin.java:156)
org.apache.wss4j.common.crypto.CryptoFactory.getInstance(CryptoFactory.java:119)
org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JUtils.loadCryptoFromPropertiesFile(WSS4JUtils.java:300)
org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.AbstractWSS4JInterceptor.loadCryptoFromPropertiesFile(AbstractWSS4JInterceptor.java:221)
org.apache.wss4j.dom.handler.WSHandler.loadCrypto(WSHandler.java:979)
org.apache.wss4j.dom.handler.WSHandler.loadSignatureCrypto(WSHandler.java:874)
org.apache.wss4j.dom.handler.WSHandler.doSenderAction(WSHandler.java:158)
org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor.access$100(WSS4JOutInterceptor.java:57)
org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor$WSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessageInternal(WSS4JOutInterceptor.java:275)
org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor$WSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessage(WSS4JOutInterceptor.java:147)
org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor$WSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessage(WSS4JOutInterceptor.java:132)
org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:530)
org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:441)
org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:356)
org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:314)
org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:140)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy197.bulkRequestTransmitter(Unknown Source)
com.myapp.transmission.irsservices.CXFWebServiceHelper.callTransmitterWebService(CXFWebServiceHelper.java:135)
com.myapp.transmission.controllers.SubmitController.doGet(SubmitController.java:131)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Some additional info as I've looked into it further:

JDK version is:

```
openjdk version "1.9.0_191"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
```

Using Gradle to build the project. I also have discovered that when running it locally I get a security exception that seems to come later in the process. So I think the class is being properly loaded when run locally, but not on the remote server. But how can I be able to print out the class info both locally and remotely without exception?

Here's the full dependency section of my `build.gradle.kts` file (note I've taken out the direct bouncy castle dependency. Same version is pulled in either way):

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.mongodb:bson:3.6.4")
    implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.1")
    implementation("commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.3.1")
    implementation("commons-io:commons-io:2.4")
    implementation("commons-lang:commons-lang:2.3")
    implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1")
    implementation("com.google.guava:guava:19.0")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.7.0")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.0.rc2")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.0.rc2")
    implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.3")
    implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.1.3")
    implementation("org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:3.6.4")
    implementation("org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-core:3.6.4")
    implementation("org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox-app:2.0.17")
    implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7")
    implementation("org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.5.0")
    implementation("org.apache.cxf:apache-cxf:3.1.18")
    implementation("org.jetbrains:annotations:18.0.0")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")

    providedCompile("javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0")
    providedCompile("javax.mail:javax.mail-api:1.6.2")

    testImplementation("httpunit:httpunit:1.7")
}
```

Comment: What distribution of Java 8 - Oracle, OpenJDK? and what precise version?

Comment: 1. Have you verified that your Webapp does not contain two versions of the same lib ? Sometimes (especially with maven builds) you can have such problems. 
2. Have you checked libraries provided by Tomcat itself ? They are loaded first-hand, and could override your own app libs at runtime.
3. Are there other applications running besides your own on the Tomcat instance ? In some cases, there can be a classloder clash.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducer project?

Comment: Please provide a dependency report of your project. And what's the **exact** output of your log statement in your first code example?

Comment: @CoreyThan Could you share the dependencies section of your build.gradle?

Comment: @CoreThan, The CXF parent project for this version (3.3.5) uses a different version of BouncyCastle (The 1.64). Could you upgrade in order to use the same one? More details here: https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/cxf-3.3.5/parent/pom.xml#L90

Comment: When I run the `gradle dependencies` command for your dependencies I get two references to bcprov-jdk15on, one with version 1.50 and another with version 1.51 (I think Gradle resolve the latest). But CXF 3.1.18 comes with the 1.60 version (https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/cxf-3.1.18/parent/pom.xml#L76). Could you upgrade to 1.60?

Comment: @Adam OpenJDK version `1.8.0_191`

Comment: @CoreyThan for the classpath, you can use this code to print the current one: 
`(java.net.URLClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader() as java.net.URLClassLoader).getURLs().forEach({println(it.getFile())})`

Comment: @amanin I did check those, but they didn't look offhand like they were pulling in any bouncy castle versions. But looking again, the `/usr/share/tomcat/lib` folder of Tomcat has been messed with. And an environment difference like that certainly could be the source of the problem. It doesn't contain bouncycastle or apache-cxf tho. The manually added files seem to be `commons-collections` `commons-dbcp` `commons-pool` `jasper-jdt.jar` `log4j.jar` `tomcat-el` `tomcat-jsp` `tomcat-juli` and `tomcat-servlet`.

Comment: What language are you using that you can do `val classPath = SubjectPublicKeyInfo::class.java`?

Comment: @KarolDowbecki It's Kotlin.

Comment: @SHoko I tried multiple permutations of Apache CXF and both direct and indirect bouncycastle dependencies. All the versions of bouncy castle contain the class in question though, and note it is `NoClassDefFound` as opposed to (what I am more accustomed to) `ClassNotFound`. The class is definitely present, at least on the classpath the app starts up with. I can try again with `1.60` tho.

Comment: @amanin I solved it! I'd considered it could be due to your question #2, but you inspired me to rebuild the remote server's Tomcat from scratch, which was easier than I expected and solved the issue. One of the manually modified libraries in Tomcat's libs must have caused a different version of Bouncy Castle to get loaded. If you want to post an answer I'll award you the bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a dependency clash between a library in your application and one loaded by Tomcat. Note that all libraries  embedded in Tomcat `lib` folder prevail over the ones  deployed in your app, as Tomcat provide them through its Common Classloader. More detail  in officialise doc: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html

Happy to help !